# Sort array by value type

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

One array contains both numeric strings and mixed string values. How to sort this array and print numeric values first and remaining strings after?

```
String[] s = {"1","2","13","13a","10","10a","1a","1,"};
```

I want output like this --> `1 10 13 2 1, 10a 13a 1a`

i am trying like this , and i got correct output but i want make it as easy way

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import java.util.regex.*;  

public class sortprog {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] s={"1","2","13","13a","10","10a","1a","1,"};
    ArrayList alnubers=new ArrayList();
    ArrayList alstrings=new ArrayList();
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
    {
    if(Pattern.matches("[0-9]+",s[i]))
    {
        alnubers.add(s[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        alstrings.add(s[i]);
    }
    }
    /*for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
    {
        String str=s[i];
        for ( int j = 0; j < str.length(); ++j )
        {
            char c = str.charAt(j);
            int k = (int) c;
            //System.out.println("ASCII OF "+c +" = " + k + ".");
            if(k>=48&&k<=57)
            {
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
            count=0;
            break;
            }
            }
        if(count!=0)
        {
            alnubers.add(str);  
            count=0;
        }
        else
        {
            alstrings.add(str);
            count=0;
        }
    }*/
    String[] sarr = new String[alstrings.size()];
    alstrings.toArray(sarr);
    Arrays.sort(sarr);
    String[] narr = new String[alnubers.size()];
    alnubers.toArray(narr);
    Arrays.sort(narr);
    String[] finalarr=new String[sarr.length+narr.length];
    for(int l=0;l<narr.length;l++)
    {
        finalarr[l]=narr[l];
    }
    int i=0;
    for(int l=narr.length;l<sarr.length+narr.length;l++)
    {
        finalarr[l]=sarr[i];
        i++;
    }

    for(int f=0;f<finalarr.length;f++)
    {
       System.out.println(finalarr[f]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean "sorting" instead of "shorting"?

Comment: Check the parseInt function https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)
You can catch the NumberFormatException for Strings and separate them out. Then sort the numbers and strings separately.

Comment: @NavjotSingh Always avoid exceptions in otherwise correct code.

Answer (score 0):

You can call sort with your own comparator:

```
String[] s = { "1", "2", "13", "13a", "10", "10a", "1a", "1," };
Arrays.sort(s, new Comparator<String>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(String arg0, String arg1) {
        if (arg0.matches("\\d+")
                && !arg1.matches("\\d+")) {
            return -1;
        } else if (!arg0.matches("\\d+")
                && arg1.matches("\\d+")) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

});
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
```

What this does is create a comparator that makes strings containing just digits (`\\d`) of lower order than things that don't, so they will come first when sorted.

You can put in any code you like in the comparator, so if you want to have a number followed by a comma first, then this is easy to do.

Comment: List<String> l = Arrays.asList(s);         error coming hear

Comment: Yeah, the list wasn't really necessary. I like collections. Removed that part from the answer though. Note that if the comparator gets too complex you could decide to calculate a value for each string and then compare the two values.